# The Switches can not get through by both FastEthernet switchport.

Tags: cisco, switch, packet-tracer

I have two Switch 2950T-24 in my Cisco Packet Tracer, and I want connect their FastEthernet port.

But I wait a long time the triangular symbol do not turn green.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, you should accept it so that it doesn't keep popping up. Alternatively, you could provide an answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the straight-through line, you should use the Copper Cross-Over to connect two quits network device.

You can found more information in [there](http://www.cables-solutions.com/difference-between-straight-through-and-crossover-cable.html)

> Use crossover cables for the following cabling:
>
> Switch to switch
>      Switch to hub
>      Hub to hub
>       Router to router
>       Router Ethernet port to PC NIC
>       PC to PC

Comment: Why you think the `Router Ethernet port to PC NIC` is two peer to peer device?